# RakeTask.rspec_opts are ignored when specified in rake

Tags: rspec, rake, formatter

I have a RakeTask that is defined in a file test.rake as

```ruby
RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:pit) do |spec|
  spec.ruby_opts = "-I lib:spec"
  spec.rspec_opts = "--format html --out output.html --format documentation"
  spec.pattern = 'test.rb'
end

task :pi => [:report, :pit]
```

When I run the command

```bash
$ rake -f test.rake pi
```

the test runs fine. However, I do not see any output as per documentation formatter, and no `output.html` is generated.

However, when I run the command

```bash
$ rspec test.rb --format html --out output.html --format documentation
```

the test runs fine, the output is printed in documentation format, and `output.html` is also generated properly.

When I run the `rake` command, I can also see the arguments properly, the actual command looks like so:

```bash
$ ruby.exe -I lib:spec -S rspec test.rb --format html --out output.html
--format documentation
```

So, the arguments are passed in correctly, and still the format options have no effect. Could you please help me resolve this mystery.

Comment: you are using `--format` twice

Comment: @ajahongir you're allowed to provide that multiple times if you'd like multiple copies of output.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I used

```
spec.rspec_opts "--format documentation --color"
```

--color argument was not passed.

The only solution was to set it in spec_helper.rb - not in rake task

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.color = true
  config.tty = true
  config.formatter = :documentation # :progress, :html, :textmate
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
spec.rspec_opts = ["--format", "html", "--out", "output.html", "--format", "documentation"]
```